# std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::ostream>> compiles in one place, but fails in other

Tags: c++

In my project I have the following piece of code, which works perfectly fine:

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <ostream>

using optional_stream_ref = std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::ostream>>;
```

which is then used in functions such as this:

```cpp
template<typename State, typename Matrix>
inline auto state_energy(const State& state, Matrix& matrix, optional_stream_ref out = std::nullopt) -> typename State::energy_t
{
    typename State::energy_t energy = state.calc_energy(matrix, out);
    return energy;
}
```

This compiles and works.

But for some reason when I try to do it in vacuum, just testing, it doesn't compile.
This is `main.cpp` example:

```cpp
#include<optional>
#include<ostream>

using optional_stream_ref = std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::ostream>>;

void f(int a, optional_stream_ref out = std::nullopt)
{
   
}

int main()
{
    
}
```

which gives this compilation error:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Ilib/ -DNDEBUG main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/move.h:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/nested_exception.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/exception:144,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__is_trivially_copy_constructible_impl<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> >, true>’:
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:1164:12:   required from ‘struct std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> > >’
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:2945:25:   required from ‘constexpr const bool std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> > >’
/usr/include/c++/9/optional:656:11:   required from ‘class std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> > >’
main.cpp:7:60:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:1157:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> >’
 1157 |     struct __is_trivially_copy_constructible_impl<_Tp, true>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:2020:11: note: declaration of ‘class std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> >’
 2020 |     class reference_wrapper;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘constexpr const bool std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> > >’:
/usr/include/c++/9/optional:656:11:   required from ‘class std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> > >’
main.cpp:7:60:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:2945:25: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> > >’
 2945 |   inline constexpr bool is_trivially_copy_constructible_v =
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__is_trivially_move_constructible_impl<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> >, true>’:
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:1185:12:   required from ‘struct std::is_trivially_move_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> > >’
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:2948:25:   required from ‘constexpr const bool std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> > >’
/usr/include/c++/9/optional:656:11:   required from ‘class std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> > >’
main.cpp:7:60:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:1178:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> >’
 1178 |     struct __is_trivially_move_constructible_impl<_Tp, true>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:2020:11: note: declaration of ‘class std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> >’
 2020 |     class reference_wrapper;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘constexpr const bool std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> > >’:
/usr/include/c++/9/optional:656:11:   required from ‘class std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> > >’
main.cpp:7:60:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:2948:25: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::is_trivially_move_constructible<std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> > >’
 2948 |   inline constexpr bool is_trivially_move_constructible_v =
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why can it compile in one place, but fail in another?
Where is the error?

Thanks!

Comment: When your first error states `invalid use of incomplete type ...`, your compiler is telling you that type has not been defined.  Your first move is to find out [where that type is defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#include <functional>` to get the canonical definition of `std::reference_wrapper`.

As a general rule, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) includes the `#include` required for each `std` library template and type.  So I just google it ("reference wrapper cppreference", misspellings ok) and look at the top of the page.

C++ `std` header files are free to include other `std` header files, types and template, or forward declare them.  But if you want to reliably and portably use a template or type from `std`, you need to `#include` the correct header.

To diagnose this problem yourself from an error-stream, first look for the first `error` in it:

> ```
> /usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:1157:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> >’
> ```

It states `std::reference_wrapper` is incomplete.  Then you can try to work out why this error is generated either from that one line, or you can follow the "breadcrumbs" of how you got there.  Here, simply looking at that error line makes the solution relatively obvious; find a way to make `std::reference_wrapper` complete.

(I had seen this problem before, so I just assumed the `std` construct you didn't obviously `#include` a header for was missing, without having to look at your error messages.)